# IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen

Tags: openvpn, gentoo

I have a gentoo router with two openvpn instances (v2.4.6, udp and tcp) and every minute I always see this log messages:

```
Sep 12 15:42:50 lowpower2 openvpn[6505]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 15:42:50 lowpower2 openvpn[18725]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 15:43:51 lowpower2 openvpn[6505]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 15:43:51 lowpower2 openvpn[18725]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 15:44:53 lowpower2 openvpn[6505]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 15:44:53 lowpower2 openvpn[18725]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
```

For example, on tun1 (tcp) server side, when the vpn is not in use, that is no client is connected, with tcpdump I see this:

```
lowpower2 ~ # tcpdump -n -X -i tun1
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
15:37:42.981853 unknown ip 15
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 88a2 1000  ................
        0x0010:  ffff ff01 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
15:38:44.421849 unknown ip 15
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 88a2 1000  ................
        0x0010:  ffff ff01 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
15:39:45.861854 unknown ip 15
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 88a2 1000  ................
        0x0010:  ffff ff01 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

This is the server configuration for udp

```
user nobody
group nobody

port 563
proto udp
multihome
dev tun0
persist-key
persist-tun

ca /etc/openvpn/server-multi/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server-multi/lowpower2.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server-multi/lowpower2.key
dh /etc/openvpn/server-multi/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server-multi/ta.key 0

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/server-udp-multi/ipp.txt

server 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248"
push "route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.12.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.13.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.14.0 255.255.255.0"

keepalive 10 60
verb 3
max-clients 10
```

This is the server configuration for tcp

```
user nobody
group nobody

port 1494
proto tcp-server
dev tun1
persist-key
persist-tun

ca /etc/openvpn/server-multi/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server-multi/lowpower2.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server-multi/lowpower2.key
dh /etc/openvpn/server-multi/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server-multi/ta.key 0

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/server-tcp-multi/ipp.txt

server 192.168.21.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.248"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.12.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.13.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.14.0 255.255.255.0"

keepalive 10 60
verb 3
max-clients 10
```

This are the use flags:

```
Installed versions:  2.4.6(08:40:56 PM 09/11/2018)(iproute2 ssl -down-root -examples -inotify -libressl -lz4 -lzo -mbedtls -pam -pkcs11 -plugins -selinux -static -systemd -test KERNEL="linux" USERLAND="-BSD")
```

This the kernel:

```
Linux lowpower2 4.14.65-gentoo #3 SMP Thu Sep 6 22:05:43 CEST 2018 x86_64 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D425 @ 1.80GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

What is it due to? What type of packet is it? Is it possible to eliminate the warning message without decreasing the verbosity level?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/233396/93232 took me like 1 minute to find this on google

Comment: Kiwy, read my post with care, the clients are NON CONNECTED, that is the server is IDLE

Comment: Kiwy, I've edit the post to be more accurate

Comment: roaima, post edited with configuration

Comment: You can always use the "mute" directive to mute those repetitive messages.  Just put "mute 10" in there and it'll stop printing them in the log after it prints 10 of them.

Comment: @Q23 set mute 2 , but mute do not mute...
Sep 12 23:22:05 lowpower2 openvpn[3969]: NOTE: --mute triggered...
Sep 12 23:22:05 lowpower2 openvpn[3969]: 1 variation(s) on previous 2 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Sep 12 23:22:05 lowpower2 openvpn[3969]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Sep 12 23:22:36 lowpower2 openvpn[3969]: IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen
Sep 12 23:22:36... 
Sep 12 23:23:38... 
Sep 12 23:23:38... 
Sep 12 23:24:39... 
Sep 12 23:24:39... 
Sep 12 23:25:41... 
Sep 12 23:25:41... 
(messages cut to not exeed comment lenght)

Comment: Hello, I have answer your first question. This site work as a Q&A site, if you ask a question and have the answer, you should accept this answer. If this answer triggers a second question, you should ask it seperatly. I invite you to restore your original question and ask a new one with all the details you put in this one. You can also reference your previous question for better understanding. Have a nice day

Comment: mean that someone might try to connect to the VPN with wrong parameter

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**
This question use to be, Why I have those error, not how can i solve the issue. I leave my answer as it might be useful to others.
**End of Edit**
According to this post [OpenVPN Logs “IP Packet with unknown IP version=15”](https://askubuntu.com/q/233396/93232)  and [this thread](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=22672) :

> It's a common error happening when there's a difference in compression configuration between the server and the client.

Comment: Initial version of the question has tcpdum in it. So Sir, can you please elaborate how your "answer" explains it? What makes you believe it's somehow related to the question? Which byte makes you think it's somehow compression related?

Comment: Well my answers points to 2 differents possible solutions and it is a very common issue which is bad pratice i admit and this answer is 5 years old, if you feel like it should be removed because of it's poor quality please contact the mods.

Answer (score 2):

These errors have nothing to do with difference in compression configuration between the openvpn server and client because there is no interaction between them.

According to this post https://www.toofishes.net/blog/openvpn-and-aoe-interaction/ these errors messages are exclusively triggered by the AoE kernel module.

Comment: This error may also appear when the server is configured for `tun` but the client is configured for `tap`.

Comment: This should be accepted answer because of 88a2 in the tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with ARP broadcast frames being "pushed" into the tun interface which looks like this in tcpdump:

```
20:30:01.461071 unknown ip 15
0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 0806 0001  ................
0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 0000 0000 0000 0a09 0002  ................
0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0a09 00bd

unknown physical layer type 0xfffe
```

The source is the new network discovery "feature" from ntopng. Many thanks for "developers" :)

As a result my logs where full of messages like this:

```
message repeated 504 times: [ server/<ip>:<port> IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen]
```

Unfortunately netfilter appears to be absolutely useless there.
tun interface is Level 3 and what left are ip v4 tables and ip v6 tables but there are no ip v15 tables in netfilter right?
and all that junk just comes through netfilter by default. Sad.
So without adding some C code (sorry not today) it looks like there is nothing could be done with netfilter.

Even XDP doesn't looks like an option. At least I'd never used it with outgoing packets and it's also requires a little coding anyway.

The only thing left I could think about was egress qdisc:

```
:~# tc qdisc add dev tun1 clsact
:~# tc filter add dev tun1 egress prio 1 u32 match u8 0xf0 0xf0 at 0 action drop
```

which appears to be still working just fine with my kernel:

```
:~# tc -s -d filter show dev tun1 egress
filter protocol all pref 1 u32 chain 0
filter protocol all pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800: ht divisor 1
filter protocol all pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 terminal flowid ??? not_in_hw
  match f0000000/f0000000 at 0
        action order 1: gact action drop
        Action statistics:
        Sent 1536 bytes 12 pkt (dropped 12, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
        backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

No more spam in the logs.